ADO CI conditions not working for branching strategy
Hi I have to set branching strategy, this is my CI template which is loaded into main pipeline, but the condition rules are not working, here is my code:
feature branches can only merge into develop, develop can only merge into release, and release can only merge into master
jobs:
- job: ci_pipeline
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    fetchDepth: 2

  # Branch rule validation with conditional checks for pull request environment
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Validate Branch Rules'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        # Check if running in a Pull Request context
        if ("$(Build.Reason)" -eq "PullRequest") {
          # Debug output to check the branches involved
          Write-Host "Pull Request ID: $(System.PullRequest.PullRequestId)"
          Write-Host "Base Branch (Target): $(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)"
          Write-Host "Head Branch (Source): $(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)"

          $baseRef = "$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)"
          $headRef = "$(System.PullRequest.SourceBranch)"

          # Enforce branch merging rules with regex for precise matching
          if ($baseRef -eq 'refs/heads/develop' -and ($headRef -notmatch '^refs/heads/feature/.*')) {
              Write-Error "Feature branches can only merge into develop"
              exit 1
          }
          elseif ($baseRef -eq 'refs/heads/release' -and $headRef -ne 'refs/heads/develop') {
              Write-Error "Develop can only merge into release"
              exit 1
          }
          elseif ($baseRef -eq 'refs/heads/master' -and $headRef -ne 'refs/heads/release') {
              Write-Error "Release can only merge into master"
              exit 1
          }
        } else {
          Write-Host "This build is not triggered by a PullRequest. Variables for PR are not available."
        }
      pwsh: true


What exactly is not working? Any Error? What is printed?
